# How to get the innertext alone without the child tags using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML page like below. I need to take the 'blah blah blah' alone from the 'span' tag.

```
<span class="news">
blah blah blah
<div>hello</div>
<div>bye</div> 
</span>
```

This gives me all values:

```
div.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='news']").InnerText.Trim();
```

This gives me null:

```
div.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='news']/preceding-sibling::text()").InnerText.Trim();
```

How do I get the text before the 'div' tag using HtmlAgilityPack?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your 2nd try was pretty close. Use `/text()` instead of `/preceding-sibling::text()`, because the text node is *child* of the `span[@class='news']` not *sibling* (neither preceding nor following) :

```
div.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='news']/text()")
   .InnerText
   .Trim();
```

Comment: Great piece of answer and thanks for pointing out my mistake!